# How to delete rows from SQL table simultaneously selecting from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete all rows from a table except the one having the max `revision_id` value simultaneously selecting data from the same table:

```sql
delete from
  node_revision__body
where
  entity_id=4 
  and revision_id not in (
    select
      max(revision_id)
    from
      node_revision__body
    where
      entity_id=4
    )
```

That throws the error

> You can't specify target table 'node_revision__body' for update in
> FROM clause

Is it possible to somehow change the query in order to achieve the goal?

Comment: does it work without the sub-select? as in `delete from
  node_revision__body
where
  entity_id=4 
  and revision_id not in (1,2,3)`

Comment: only by views I guess...

Comment: @JoSSte yes, it works without the sub-select

Comment: and many more duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can%27t+specify+target+table+for+update+in+FROM+clause+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) "feature" of MySql, you cannot update the same table as you select from, however a few workarounds exist, for example you can try nesting the query one level deeper:

```
delete from node_revision__body
where entity_id = 4 
  and revision_id not in (
    select revision_id from (
      select max(revision_id) revision_id
      from node_revision__body
      where entity_id = 4
    )b
);
```

See a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WvsvVa0E)

Comment: Thanks! Is it a typo `)b` before the last row?

Comment: that is a shorthand `as b`

Comment: I haven't tried the code but no, `b` is the required derived table alias.

Comment: @Stu I don't know why, but it doesn't work. I get "0 rows affected" and when I run select, I still see all the rows in the table

Comment: @Stu Perhaps because `revision_id` is the primary key?

Comment: @stckvrw I spotted the possible problem I think, I edited above, the `max(revision_id)` should also be aliased otherwise it won't exist for the outer query - see [working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WvsvVa0E)